# Hypothesis testing: carrying capacity of bridges

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

> A manufacturer claims that, at the moment of stockage, the carrying
>   capacity (CC) of the produced bridges follows a normal distribution
>   with $\mu = 2500\, kg$ and $\sigma^2=150^2\, kg^2$. Moreover the CC of
>   the different bridges are independent. The CC of the bridges decreases
>   as time goes by, so after 2 years the manufacturer has to decide
>   whether to get rid of the bridges or not (independence, normality and
>   variance are assumed to be preserved!).
>
> How many bridges do we have to test such that
>
> - if the average CC is $2500\, kg$, then this can be claimed with a certainty of $95\%$.
> - if the average CC decreases by $150\, kg$, then it is possible to detect this decrement with a probability of $90\%$.

*My attempt:*

We set $H_0: \mu = 2500$ and $H_A: \mu < 2500$. Suppose that $\bar{X}$ denotes the average CC of bridges in a sample of size $n$. Then it is clear that $\bar{X} = N(2500,150^2/n)$ under $H_0$, where $n$ is the unknown we're solving for.

The first bullet points assumes that we're working under the assumption that $H_0$ is true. The second one states that $\bar{X} = N(2350,150^2/n)$. I feel like I'll have a system of two equations to solve for $n$. I just don't know how the express 'being able to detect with a probability of $\alpha\%$' mathematically. I feel like confidence intervals are an option.

For the first one, we have that the sample average will lie in $$[2500-1,96\cdot \frac{150}{\sqrt n}, 2500+1,96\cdot \frac{150}{\sqrt n}].$$ And then we can do the same for the second bullet point. But how do I find $n$ from these intervals?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me there is some missing info in the first case, though I am not really sure. Rejection/acceptance criterion is however given below. $Z = \frac{\bar{X} -2500}{150/\sqrt{n}}$.

The second one I believe we are able to solve as following:

Having a rejection criterion from the hypothesis test $Z < k$, where $Z$ is your test observator, standard normally distributed under $H_0$. Let's say you have one of 95%, then $k = -1.64$ (remember to use in this case a one sided interval!). Now, I guess what they are asking for, is finding the probability of rejecting $H_0$ to be 90%, i.e.

$$
P(Z<k \;|\; \mu = 2350) = 0.9, \quad Z = \frac{\bar{X}-2500}{150/\sqrt{n}}, \quad k = -1.64
$$

In this case, $Z$ is no longer standard normally distributed, hence we have to manipulate the inequality, by adding $150/(150\sqrt{n})$. Then the left hand side is normally distributed, thus

$$
P(Z^* < -1.64 + \sqrt{n}) = 0.9 \quad \Rightarrow -1.64 + \sqrt{n} = 1.28 \; \text{(from quantile table)}
$$

From this, $n$ has to be at least $8.52$, thus this answer will give $n=9$.